# Chrome is rendering text weirdly

Tags: google-chrome, sonoma

What the title says, in the image below you can see what exactly is happening, a normal text is rendered weirdly in Chrome, it looks like the characters shown are shifted with respect to what the actual text contains, e.g. instead of 'g' I get rendered 'f' or 'w' instead of 'x' and so on. In the image left side is Chrome and right side is Safari. Any idea on what caused this and how can I fix it?

My specs are, OS: Sonoma 14.3 running on M1 2020, Chrome: 123.0.6312.58 (Official Build) (arm64) which as of date is the latest version.

I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

[image: Example of what's happening]

PD: the code that generated this webpage.

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=windows-1252"><title></title></head><body>
```

## Example

This is a dummy text rendered in Chrome and rendered in Safari, as you can see the text in Chrome gets rendered wrongly: "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."

---

nginx

Comment: I see the same, in Chrome and in all Chromium-based browsers.

Comment: You mean it is like a widespread error?

Comment: Does https://thethreevirtues.com/ render correctly for you? I started to notice this [two weeks ago](https://smnn.ch/@nohillside/112047436730307893), but it doesn‘t happen on all my Macs/in all user accounts.

Comment: Yes, the webpage you mention renders weirdly. In my case not all webpages render like this, it happens in some specific ones, also in some email body text/signatures.

Comment: Am I supposed to see the text above render incorrectly on this page? Or am I supposed to build my own webpage using the HTML code provided? Either way, I can't reproduce this in Vivaldi, which is Chromium-based, FWIW.

Comment: @benwiggy you can also try my links. But it may very well depend on local conditions, I don’t see it on all my Macs.

Comment: @nohillside No problems with those pages in Vivaldi either.

Comment: @benwiggy [Well...](https://smnn.ch/nohillside/sharing/6ad3c42ed789d6df2ca7b7e84af10b4e/vivaldi.png) I'm fully aware that it is something specific to my Mac account (it doesn't happen on other accounts on the same machine), and basically a rendering issue (copy/paste into Textedit works correctly). But the potential causes are endless, would hope for some pointers at least ...

Comment: @nohillside I presume you've cleared the font cache and restarted?

Comment: @benwiggy I actually didn't. That's `atsutil databases -remove`, right?

Comment: @nohillside Something like that, yes. You need to restart anyway, so I usually just boot into Safe mode, and restart again, which also clears them.

Comment: @benwiggy Unfortunately, this didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, with Chromium based browsers showing gibberish when rendering https://thethreevirtues.com/ and other pages. Took some debugging, at the end it was a corrupted font file for "Times" which I had installed locally (in `~/Library/Fonts`) to [fix a Java-related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68608157/how-can-i-fix-this-warning-the-fonts-times-and-times-are-not-available-fo) a while ago. Removing this file and restarting Chrome solved the issue.